# Jquery conditionally setting google map variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a hard time with my script. Basically I have it read a country_code from an input box and then use this as the country filter for the google map places autosuggest. This code works and can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/5dqHg/23/

It pulls the country code from this field:

```
<input class="hidden" id="#ctry" disabled="true" value="us"></input>
```

My problem is this field will not always be set, so when it isnt I have this:

```
<input class="hidden" id="#ctry" disabled="true" value=""></input>
```

But this breaks the autosuggestion, when really it should not apply a country filter to the autosuggest and show places from every country.

I guess in sudo code I need something like this:

```
var ctryiso = $("#ctry").val();
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], {
  types: ["geocode"],
<if ctryiso !=null then>
  componentRestrictions: {
    country: ctryiso
  }
</if>

});
```

I also tried this technique without any success:

```
if (ctryiso) { options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso }; }
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to only set a country restriction filter if there is one found in the country input box like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an options variable and pass it in after a conditional check.

```
var ctryiso = $("#ctry").val();
var options;
if(ctryiso != ''){
    options = {
      types: ["geocode"],
      componentRestrictions: {
                 country: ctryiso
      }
    }
}else{
    options = {types: ["geocode"]}
}
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], options); // <-- pass in the options
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YgQc9/)

You can compact it to this..

```
var ctryiso = $("#ctry").val();
var options = {
     types: ["geocode"]
};
if(ctryiso != ''){
    options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso };        
}
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], options);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hgtxm/)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work but it also seems quite large code, is there a way to compact it?

Comment: if(ctryiso != ''){ options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso }; }   - I dont understand why that doesnt work

Comment: Hi I said that your code does work but it just seems quite large to the code I posted, except for what ever reason the code I posted doesnt work but yours does

Comment: @Jimmy Oh yeah sorry, I should have been more clear - I was actually referring to this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026406/jquery-conditionally-setting-google-map-variable/17026586?noredirect=1#comment24609809_17026586) when I said it was working :P